# If a theory has a countable $\omega$-saturated model does it need to have only countable many countable models?

Tags: model-theory

If a theory has countably many countable models (up to isomorphism) then it has at countably many types, and it follows that there exists a countable $\omega$-saturated model of such theory.

If a theory has a countable $\omega$-saturated model then it has at most countably many types, but I can't see why (if at all) it follows that the theory has then at most countably many models (modulo isomorphism). Is this converse true?

Comment: I want to add to this thread that a follow-up question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2370590/omega-stable-theories-in-finite-relational-language/2374012#2374012). Levon Haykazyan pointed out that the theory DCF$_0$ is $\omega$-stable (in particular has countably many types over the empty set) but has continuum-many countable models (Corollary 2.6 of Chapter 3 of "Model Theory of Fields" by Marker, Messmer and Pillay).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not true. The idea for producing a counterexample is to make sure that there are only countably many types, but also to make sure that countably many of them are non-isolated, so that they can be omitted and realized at will. This will give continuum many models, depending on which subset of the non-isolated types are realized.

Here's the simplest explicit counterexample that I could see:

Let $\{P_i\,|\, i\in\omega\}$ be unary predicates, and let $\{c_{i,j}\,|\,i,j\in\omega\}$ be constant symbols.

$T$ asserts that the predicates are disjoint and the constants are distinct, and it assigns countably many constants to each predicate, i.e.
$T = \{\lnot\exists x\, P_i(x)\land P_j(x)\,|\,i\neq j\} \cup \{c_{i,j}\neq c_{i',j}\,|\,i\neq i'\} \cup \{P_i(c_{i,j})\,|\,i,j\in\omega\}$.

The standard arguments for toy theories like this show that $T$ has quantifier elimination and is complete. The key thing is that each type $p_i(x): \{P_i(x)\} \cup \{x\neq c_{i,j}\,|\,j\in\omega\}$, asserting that $x$ is an unnamed element satisfying $P_i$, is non-isolated.

$T$ has a countable $\omega$-saturated model $M$, which has countably many unnamed elements satisfying each $P_i$, plus countably many elements not satisfying any $P_i$.

But $T$ also has continuum many non-isomorphic models. For any $S\subseteq \omega$, let $M_S$ be a model which has one unnamed element satisfying $P_i$ for all $i\in S$ and no unnamed element satisfying $P_i$ for all $i\notin S$.

Comment: Trivial point: to make $T$ complete you need it to assert that the constants are all different.

Comment: You're right - thanks! I've updated the answer.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but found it while trying to understand some things, how would you prove that this thing is complete and has QE?? I would like to know that.

Comment: There are many tests for QE, for example the one from Marker's book quoted in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178231/about-the-proof-of-a-test-for-quantifier-elimination) math.SE question. Try to use this test to demonstrate QE for this theory. Once you have QE, completeness is not hard: A theory with QE is complete if and only if it decides every quantifier-free *sentence*. And in this case it's easy to make a list of all the atomic sentences and see that they're decided by $T$.